# How to watch an hdfs directory and copy the latest file that arrives in hdfs to local?

Tags: python, bash, hdfs, inotify

I want to write a script in `bash/python` such that the script copies the latest file which arrives at `hdfs` directory.I know I can use `inotify` in local, but how to implement it in `hdfs?`
Can you please share the sample code for it. When I searched for it in google it gives me long codes.Is there a simpler way other than `inotify`(if its too complex)

Comment: _arrives latest_ as in the file that was most recently written?

Comment: yes, the recent one

Comment: Do not edit the question to answer. Just post it.

Comment: It was not the answer , I suggested the code of inotify in local!

Answer (score 0):

Inelegant hack:

Mount hdfs using FUSE then periodically use `find <mountpoint> -cmin n` to get a list of files created in the last n minutes.

Then use `find <mountpoint> -anewer` to sort them.